# Stopping AutoPostBack from going back to the top of the page

Tags: asp.net

So like the title states I want to stop AutoPostBack from sending the user back to the top of the page. I want to know if it's possible.

By the way: I know about AJAX's UpdatePanel, but that's too troublesome. I'd like to keep things simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"` on your page directive as below

```
<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" ... %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been trying for 3 hours now.

Answer (score 0):

we can use this MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" on your page directive as below

and the second if this dosn't work
code in code behind me.

Page.SmartNavigation = true;

in page load

and i anodher solution is Use an UpdatePanel control to asynchronously update parts of a page